# Valid parameters for GMP's mpz_mod_ui

Tags: c, gmp

The [documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division) of `mpz_mod_ui` states it's interface as:

```
unsigned long int mpz_mod_ui (mpz_t r, const mpz_t n, unsigned long int d);
```

That essentially computes `r = n % d`, which is a non-negative integer less than `d`, also the function result; or cause a division by zero if `d == 0`.

Is it OK to set the `r` parameter to `NULL`, meaning we do not need an `mpz_t` set to the result?

In C, `unsigned long int` is not fixed size. It's at-least-32-bit, but is often 64-bit. Is GMP supported on platforms with various size of `unsigned long int`? Is the largest valid `d` always `~0UL` (or I think equivalently `ULONG_MAX` defined in `<limits.h>` of a C compiler) on all supported platforms?

Comment: https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division#index-mpz_005fmod_005fui suggests another function you can use if you do not need r. No, passing NULL for r is not ok.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: indeed `mpz_fdiv_ui` seems to be the way to go instead of `mpz_mod_ui` without result in the `r` parameter. That would be an answer for my first question.

Comment: This section of the manual may be helpful [ABI and ISA](https://gmplib.org/manual/ABI-and-ISA).

Comment: @JosephWood: so I should have read the fantastic manual. Thanks. I'll eventually answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When using `mpz_mod_ui`, is it OK to set the `r` parameter to NULL, meaning we do not need an mpz_t set to the result?

That's not advisable, and there's a better way. As noted in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/135234833), there is a function computing `n % d` for `d` that fits an `unsigned long int`:

```
unsigned long int mpz_fdiv_ui (const mpz_t n, unsigned long int d);
```

> Is GMP supported on platforms with various size of `unsigned long int`?

Yes. As noted in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/135268791), `unsigned long` can be 64-bit or 32-bit depending on GMP compilation parameters, see the [ABI and ISA documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/ABI-and-ISA). However 64-bit `unsigned long int` is increasingly supported, and is available on each supported platforms in at least one option.